# Using string methods to change DOM element parameters in Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript

If I have an object :

```
 function myClass(id) {
   this.em = document.getElementById(id);
   this.html = function(data) {
     this.em.html = data;
   }
 }
```

*Now I can :*

```
  var em = new MyClass("id");
  em.html("NEW HTML HERE");
```

*I need :*

```
em.html = "NEW HTML HERE";
```

**Is It possible?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML5 you could define a `set` method on the `html` property (see [`defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Browser_compatibility))

```
function myClass(id) {
    this.em = document.getElementById(id);    

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'html', {
        set: function(val) {
            this.em.html = val;
        }
    });
}
```

... but this will only work in the most [modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Browser_compatibility); IE8, Chrome 5, Firefox 4.

See a demo of the above working here; http://jsfiddle.net/sskKc/